# Combobox : DataTemplate for each DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have two problems, one small and one big, and I need help;

First, this is my code :

```
                <ComboBox Name="cmb1" Width="165" Height="25" Margin="25,5,10,10" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ChoicesList}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChoiceList}">
            </ComboBox>
            <ComboBox Name="cmb2" Width="165" Height="25" Margin="10,5,25,10">
                <ComboBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Sections}"></Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedChoiceList}" Value="Contract">
                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Contract}"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedChoiceList}" Value="Service">
                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Services}"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.Style>
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
                                           Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                           Margin="4,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
                                           Text="{Binding label}" 
                                           Margin="0"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
                                           Text="{Binding Start, StringFormat=d}"
                                           Margin="0"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                                           Text="{Binding End,StringFormat=d}"
                                           Margin="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
```

Another day, another problem!

1. In cmb2, I would like nothing to be loaded until I have made one of the three choices, is there a way? 
   (for the moment I load "section" list if nothing is chosen, and the binding changes according to the choices. I made this choice because the value of "section" can change, it can be "A" or "B" or "C" and more, so I would like "service" = service list, "contract" = contract list and "section"= all other values)
2. More importantly, I would like to rework this code because currently the DataTemplate is the same for all three binds, which was not awkward (If I choose "section", textblock displays "name" selected, cause section have no label, for example) but I would like, for contracts, to display "name" + "from" + "Starting date" + "To" + "Ending date".

If I add textblock "text = from" and "text = to", it will apply to all my choices, and I would have, for example, if I choose "section", a result like "nameOfSection + from + to", and I don't want that.

So I would like the textblock "from" and "to" to appear only for the choice "contract", I don't know if it's possible?

Hoping to have been clear, and thanking you for your time for the help you will give me;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

To answer your first point by removing the line that is setting the `ItemSource` you should be able to have nothing loaded

`<Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Sections}"></Setter>` can be removed and replaced with another `DataTrigger`.

To answer your second point you can use `DataTemplates` with the `DataType` property to apply a style to a specific data type. This means you can setup each of your, Service, Section and Contract to look differently / template their own properties.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type classes:Contract}">
    <Label Content="Contract"/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type classes:Service}">
    <Label Content="Service"/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type classes:Section}">
    <Label Content="Section"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

This bit of code demonstrates that.

Here is also a sample application I have made that should do what you've asked.

View

```
<Window x:Class="SOHelp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:classes="clr-namespace:SOHelp.Classes"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type classes:Contract}">
            <Label Content="Contract"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type classes:Service}">
            <Label Content="Service"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type classes:Section}">
            <Label Content="Section"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Width="165" Height="25" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ChoicesList}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChoiceList}"/>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Width="165" Height="25" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedChoiceList.Items}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind / could be ViewModel

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Option> _choicesList;
    private Option _selectedChoiceList;
    public Option SelectedChoiceList
    {
        get { return _selectedChoiceList; }
        set { _selectedChoiceList = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Option> ChoicesList
    {
        get { return _choicesList; }
        set { _choicesList = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ChoicesList = new ObservableCollection<Option>
        {
            new Option("Contract", new ObservableCollection<object>
            {
                new Contract(), new Contract(), new Contract()
            }),
            new Option("Service", new ObservableCollection<object>
            {
                new Service(), new Service(), new Service()
            }),
            new Option("Section", new ObservableCollection<object>
            {
                new Section(), new Section(), new Section()
            }),
        };

        DataContext = this;
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Classes I created

```
public class Option
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<object> Items { get; set; }
    public Option(string name, ObservableCollection<object> items)
    {
        Name = name;
        Items = items;
    }
}

public class Service
{
}

public class Section
{
}

public class Contract
{
}
```

Hope some of this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

[image: First combobox]
[image: Example of second combobox]
[image: Second example of second combobox]
[image: Nothing loaded on startup]

Comment: For the first point, if I delete and replace "Sections" with another datatrigger, I will have to give it a "value = something", and I would like it to do so in any case where value is not "contract" or "service".

For the 2nd, I didn't quite understand the principle. I feel like I have to redo all the code to match it to this Ahah

If I understood correctly, you're creating a collection in which you put the other collections?

Comment: You only have three options right? sections, contract and service. So having sections on another datatrigger will mean that when loaded if none are selected then the itemsource is nothing.
yes, I have essentially re-created your data structure, to be cleaner and more efficient. There are infinite ways to achieve the thing you're trying, I just came up with one, as I could show off data templates, which is the main idea I wanted to convey.

Comment: Yes, and I like the way you do it, I'll work on it.

In fact, "Section" is linked to a database. Depending on the company, "section" may be called "unit" or "group" or "places"... etc

Comment: Something similar to what I've shown will suit that well as you won't be hardcoding the options into the UI. this way the options are dynamically made in the UI. Goodluck, if you need anymore help feel free to dm me. :)